# Add Button to UIView Created Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiview

I created UIView and Button programmatically

```
var width = self.view.frame.width - 8
        var height = width/8

        newView.frame = CGRectMake(4, 39, width, height)
        newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.view.addSubview(newView)

        var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
        button.frame = newView.frame
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("  All Hospitals/Clinics", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
        newView.addSubview(button)
```

I want the button to be inside the UIView, and to have exactly the same location, width and height of UIView

but the result is this

[image]

What is wrong with my code ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Autolayout?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon yes i'm using autolayout, but i need this button to be created programmatically

Comment: Then, you have to give constraints also while creating UI programatically!

Comment: @SohilR.Memon constraints for the UIView and the button? is this the reason for this problem? even they have the same frame ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is caused by this line of code:

```
button.frame = newView.frame // Equivalent to button.frame = CGRectMake(4, 39, width, height)
```

In your current implementation the x position of button is 4 and y position is 39, that's why you are getting the result like that way. You need to specify the button frame relative to the newView.

Change the button frame setting code to:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `bounds` instead of the frame of the view.

```
button.frame = newView.bounds
```

Bounds returns the CGRect of the view coordinates in its own coordinate space, while frame returns the same but in it's parent's coordinate space.

So newView.bounds would return a CGRect like `(0,0,width_of_newView,height_of_newview)`

Answer (score 1):

your button frame is wrong.

when you declared x and y property of a frame, it is related to its superview.

since you declare your button frame as (4, 39, width, height) it will be placed on coordinate x = 4, y = 39 in view's frame which is exactly like your picture.

if you want to make it like your view, change x and y to 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Anchor`

```swift
lazy var testButton: UIButton = {

  let button = UIButton()

  button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
  button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
  button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
  button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

  return button

}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  self.view.addSubview(testButton)
}
```